# Hibernate: Delete all children with one query

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, parent-child, cascade

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to configure Hibernate to delete all child objects using a single delete query?

---

**Full Question:** I have the following parent/child association defined in Hibernate 5.1:

```java
public class Parent {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
  private List<Child> children;
}

public class Child {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
  private Parent parent;
}
```

When I delete the parent object, all of the child objects are deleted, as expected, but each one is deleted individually.  In my application a parent could have many thousands of children, so for performance reasons I need to use a single query to delete them all at once.

**Possible Workarounds**

1. Manually execute my own HQL query, `DELETE FROM child WHERE parent_id = ?`, prior to deleting the parent.  The downside here is that I (and any other developers) have to remember to call the method. Plus, it essentially circumvents the cascade delete.
2. Allow the cascade delete to happen at the database level. Since data is changing behind the scenes, I assume I would need to remember to manually `.clear()` the child collection to prevent disparity between Hibernate and the database.

---

**Edit:** I see older versions of Hibernate used to have the concept of a [one-shot delete](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-collections-oneshotdelete) but I cannot find anything similar in the documentation for the latest version.  Has that functionality been removed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Say you delete a Parent.
2. If some other table, say GrandChild, has a foreign key constraint
   with Child, with each Child having multiple GrandChild records, they
   need to be removed too.
3. The reason for multiple generated delete queries is, Hibernate can
   not know whether there are any foreign key constraints from other
   tables, to the "Child" table. Also there might be some call back methods that needs to executed such as @PreRemove. This is the reason why each Child reference is loaded from the database and removed individually.
4. In short, if you depend on Hibernate to manage your entities, this
   is the default behavior.
5. Either set the ON DELETE CASCADE in the data base explicitly, or mark
   the required Child entity with the annotation
   @org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete, which automatically adds the
   "on delete" to schema during the schema generation. For your example it would be,

   ```
   `@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "parent", 
               cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)    
    @org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete(
               action = @org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<Child> children;
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. If I add the cascade delete in the database will that cause problems with Hibernate's caching?

Comment: This makes some sort of sense if I don't have orphanRemoval=true, but if I do - it means that I want child to be deleted when parent is gone, means I am sure that there are no grand children or I should take care of them prior to deletion. Your point about @PreRemove is still valid though.

Comment: @AdamParod Let's say I've got Parent, Child, and Grandchild. All in OneToMany relationships. How do I delete grandchild on deletion of Parent?

Answer (score 2):

This may seem overly simple, so perhaps I'm not understanding your question correctly, but:

```
Parent parent = parentRepository.findByName("dad");
parent.getChildren().clear();
entityManager.save(parent);
```

*If only we could .clear() our children, just like that. Perhaps better to soft delete them incase we change our minds :)*

Comment: Indeed, this seems overly simple! It seemed overly simple until I tried it and to my surprise, it worked like a charm! Thank you very much! 